# autostarting program with rc.local, stuck on startup

Tags: boot

I have a program that I normally run as so:

```
sudo /home/pi/code/./main 12345
```

where 12345 is just a input. This code runs infinitely until I forcefully stop it.

However, I want my pi to do this automatically when turned on. It already automatically logs in so I tried to put the above line inside /etc/rc.local

unfortunately, when I restarted, the pi is stuck on the raspberry graphic(I'm in command line mode). Obviously this is from my program. What should I do so this program can run without obstructing everything else?

Luckily I had a backup so I can try again, but this time I'd like to do it right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have you tried to add an ampersand to your command to allow it to run in the background?

```
sudo /home/pi/code/./main 12345 &
```

Comment: no, would that be obstructive even in the background?

Comment: unless you put an ampersand, your pi is stuck wherever you call you program from, until it's finished. please, try and see?

Comment: I just did, and the function no longer seems to be working. But, the boot problem is gone!

Comment: well, now you have to fix your program =)

Comment: it works when I run manually, but not with this autoboot option. Is there an alternative I could pursue besides rc.local?

Comment: sudo expects the password, that may be the reason it won't work from the batch file. use something like: $echo <password> | sudo -S <command>

Comment: ok I'll try that. I was dumb and put sudo su first and then did the command like before. That froze the system again.

Answer (score 7):

First, running `sudo su` or `sudo` on boot is useless, as you are already running as root. Only if you want to run as a **different** user you should use the `su - user -c "command"`.
You may doing this to setup the login root `ENVIRONMENT`, but then the command is `su - -c "command"`

As for running the command, use

```
nohup /home/pi/code/./main 12345 &
```

The app is probably trying to grab a tty and in the `rc.local` you have none. `nohup`  might solve it.

If still don't work, try this one (you may need to install screen: `apt-get install screen` ):

```
screen -d -m /home/pi/code/./main 12345
```

`screen` will emulate a full terminal and run it i background. You can see it later with `screen -x` as the same user as the main process (root in this case).