# Raspberry Pi 3+ : rc.local loop issue

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, pi-3b+

I'm using a new Raspberry Pi model B+ (with Raspbian) in order to host my Django website but I have an issue when I try to go to repositories.

My website is well-hosted, I can access through http://astrophoto-val.fr to my website, but I can't access to directories inside my raspberry. I'm not connected with SSH (it doesn't work) but directly over my device.

I have this loop :

[image]

I can't write something. How can I stop all of this and access to ID/Password area in order to handle files in /var/www/html ?

I don't want to reset my SD Card :/

Thank you!

**EDIT** :

This is what I've done on **cmdline.txt** :

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=fd6771a8-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait systemd.unit=emergency.target
```

But I don't overcome, when I start my raspberry, to get access to login part. I have the loop shown on my picture and I can't make more things. Even if I use Ctrl + Alt + F2

Comment: Did you set Django to run in your rc.local? If so, you should probably see [autostarting program with rc.local, stuck on startup](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9485/autostarting-program-with-rc-local-stuck-on-startup) if you haven't explicitly set it to run in the background.

Comment: I don't know what is `rc.local` exactly. So I have never used this before. When my raspbian is launched (like my picture) I can't write something. Even if I use Ctrl + Alt + F2 for example :/

Comment: `I don't know what is rc.local exactly. So I have never used this before`  do you know what you put in it? it looks like it's trying to establish some sort of SSH connection with `67.197.150.242` - does that mean anything to you?

Comment: I'd be concerned about whatever you added to rc.local adding a chinese and taiwanese IP addresse to the "list of known hosts"

Comment: Please edit your question and add the content of your cmdline.txt to it.

Comment: @JaromandaX I have never added chinese or taiwanese IP addresses to the "list of know hosts" ! My raspbian has been corrupted by hackers ?

Comment: No idea what you've installed on your pi

Answer (score 2):

On a linux system with card reader you can mount the SD Card partition 2 and modify the files you want, also `etc/rc.local` and files in `var/www/html`.

You can also boot into *rescue.target*. Mount partition 1 an append this to `cmdline.txt`:

```
systemd.unit=rescue.target
```

Boot your RasPi with this and you should get a terminal and you can repair your system on the command line. If it doesn't help instead you can try to append to `cmdline.txt`:

```
systemd.unit=emergency.target
```

This will give you only a shell on the main console without running any other services. But maybe it's enough to fix your problem. Quoted from [Special systemd units](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html)

> emergency.target: A special target unit that starts an emergency shell on the main console. This target does not pull in any services or mounts. It is the most minimal version of starting the system in order to acquire an interactive shell; the only processes running are usually just the system manager (PID 1) and the shell process.

If you don't even get access with this target then it seems you are lost.

Comment: Thank you with your answer. But I modified my file .txt as you mentioned and I can't get any terminal in order to repair my system. I still remain blocked to `rc.local : lost connection` .... Like my picture ... Is it possible that my raspbian is corrupted by somebody ?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Don't modify *myfile.txt*, it must be the file **cmdline.txt**. Be careful and don't add extra space or new lines in it. You can also modify `/var/www/html` if partition 2 is mounted on a linux pc with a card reader.

Comment: my file .txt is the shortcut of cmdline.txt ^^ I can't get access to /var/www/html because I can't get access to login part in first time ..

Comment: @Deadpool - you must've done *something wrong™* - did you *add* `systemd.unit=rescue.target` on the first (and only) line in `cmdline.txt` on the boot partition of the sd card you boot the raspberry pi with?